# JAVA: How to get the value of the root while iterating the jsonArray which matches the value?

Tags: java, arrays

Have the **JSONResponse** as below :
**`[
  {
    "Language": "English",
    "brand": [
      "US",
      "UK"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Language": "Spanish",
    "brand": [
      "ES"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Language": "German",
    "brand": [
      "DE"
    ]
  }
]`**

How to iterator the brand attribute and match with input (example: UK).

Check the UK is present in brand and then print value of Language?

I am trying to automate using the above API response by JAVA, the language value needs to be passed to other API as request when the brand value matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the **JSONArray** and retrieve the brand array using **getJSONArray()** method on each item and then check if your input is same as any of the strings in that list using **getString()** and **compareTo()**, and then print the Language of that item if yes.

```
String input = "UK"
for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray brands = jsonObject.getJSONArray("brand");

    for (int j = 0; j < brands.length(); j++) {
       String brand = brands.getString(j);

       if(brand.compareTo(input) == 0){
          System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("Language"));
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help . It worked the way was looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can use array's indexOf method to get the index of whatever you want to search.

```
for(var x in data){
   if(data[x].brand.indexOf("UK") > -1){
     console.log(data[x].Language);
   }
}
```

Comment: the response I receive from API doesnt have the data attribute . The response is JSONArray without data as below:                                       
 https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=30782ff712ba402ca672eb34cd7c658e

Comment: just create a data variable and assign your Json to data variable.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can create a struct. Its make easy to filter objects

```
struct Languages {
     var language: String = ""
     var brand: [String] = []

     init(lang: String, code: [String]) {

         language = lang
         brand = code
       }
} 

let source : [Languages] = [Languages(lang: "English", code: [ "US", "UK" ]),
                                              Languages(lang: "Spanish", code: [ "ES" ]),
                                              Languages(lang: "German", code: [ "DE" ])]

let result = source.filter( { $0.brand.contains("UK")})
print(result) // Languages(language: "English", brand: ["US", "UK"])
```

Comment: I am trying to automate the API response and pass the request value to other API as Request using JAVA programming